# Here Document not working with sudo su

Tags: bash

I was trying to write a `setup.sh` script that searches and installs the required components while installing an application. If a required component is not found it will prompt to install it. I have used `sudo apt-get install` for that, and I want to pass the user supplied password to sudo, like this:

```
read passwd
sudo apt-get install clisp <<EOF
$passwd 
$passwd
EOF
```

But this is not working. The input password is not being passed to sudo. Why is this not happening? Is there any mistake in my usage?

Comment: Why are there two `$passwd` expressions? One for `sudo`, ok. But the second one?

Comment: Consider updating `/etc/sudoers` to allow you to run that command without a password (`NOPASSWD`, I think).  It's safer than storing your password in a file in plain text.

Answer (score 4):

The password is not read from the standard input but from the "current terminal". This is not changeable via redirection. But `sudo` provides an optione `-S` which read the password from standard input and not from the terminal.

**Edit**: A better solution to the whole problem would be to avoid intercepting the password at all. `sudo` will ask for the password itself if it requires one. using the `-A` option you can also provide a graphical UI for this question. And since `sudo` keeps a timestamp for that input it will not ask for the password the next 15 minutes (by default, i.e. configurable). Therefore multiple `sudo` calls are also not a problem.